# Frequently Asked Questions

Tags: discussion

Is there a space chunked out on SU for community approved answers to FAQ's?

For example, we see this question A LOT.

[Connecting (wireless) router to modem (with integrated router)](https://superuser.com/questions/590317/connecting-wireless-router-to-modem-with-integrated-router)

It would be easier to link to this answer rather than flog a dead horse and answer time and time again. I would link to duplicates but sometimes the selected answers include either too much or too litte info.

Answer (score 4):

We've tried to capture the essence of this with [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq). Take a look in that tag to see some examples. There's [instructions in the tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/community-faq/info) on how to submit community FAQ's. It's a fairly informal process, but there is some community review.

Generally, it's OK to close as a duplicate of a community FAQ if it answers the basic question, but it's OK for the user to refine their question and ask for it to be re-opened if the information in the community FAQ doesn't fit their situation or doesn't have a satisfactory answer. They would need to provide some information though about what they tried from the community FAQ and why it didn't work.

In general, with popular subjects like this, we want to develop high-quality "canonical answers" that give a good overview of the subject for anybody coming in with a popular question. For more information about the theory behind this, read "[The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)" on the Stack Overflow blog.

Comment: Looks good, maybe this part of SU could be easier to locate? The tagging seems a bit unintuitive.

Comment: @Scandalist I would love for this to be some sort of official feature, but unfortunately it is not. There have been various proposals for an improved system of marking canonical answers, but thus far none has gone through.